# Configurar name y email en git

Tags: git

Según la documentación oficial de `git` [Empezando - Configurando git por primera vez](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Empezando-Configurando-Git-por-primera-vez) al ejecutar el comando

```
git config --list
```

me debería listar toda la configuración que le he dado al entorno **junto con mi `user.name` y `user.email`**, mi problema es que al ejecutar este comando me devuelve este resultado:

```
git config --list

core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
credential.helper=manager
gui.recentrepo=C:/Users/jorius/Desktop/MIK
core.autocrlf=true
core.excludesfile=C:\Users\jorius\OneDrive\Documentos\gitignore_global.txt
```

El cual no me muestra dicha información, quisiera saber si esto es un "error" o si es normal que suceda, me parece curioso que no aparezca ya que si trabajo en algún repositorio no me supone ningún problema y hace los `commits` correctamente.

Comment: que valor esperas? Yo veo que si te devuelve valores de configuracion

Comment: Espero que me devuelva esos valores junto con `user.name=Scott Chacon

user.email=schacon@gmail.com`

Comment: Los configuraste anteriormente? cuando instalaste git?

Comment: Si, claro que si, si no los hubiera configurado no me permitiría hacer `push` y `commit` sin problemas, no entiendo porque no los muestra.

Comment: puedes ejecutar `git config --global -l` para ver que retorna

Comment: Me retornó esto: `git config --global -l

gui.recentrepo=C:/Users/jorius/Desktop/MIK

core.autocrlf=true

core.excludesfile=C:\Users\jorius\OneDrive\Documentos\gitignore_global.txt
`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48238/discussion-between-sioesi-and-joriusr).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

Obtienes la ruta de tu archivo `.gitconfig`

y agrega

```
[user] 
   name = Tu nombre 
   email = Tu email
```

Luego ejecuta `git config --list` y ya deberia salir estos datos en la respuesta.