# ¿Como subir un proyecto a una cuenta diferente a la anterior cuenta Github?

Tags: git, github

Desde hace tiempo estuve subiendo proyectos a Github, pero cree otra cuenta diferente que también quiero usar, sin embargo no puedo, al momento de darle el `git push -u origin master` me sale un error así:

**remote: Permission to `ElNombreMiNuevoUsuario`/pruebas.git denied to `ElNombreDeMiAnteriorUsuario`**

**fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/`ElNombreMiNuevoUsuario`/pruebas.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403**

Ya agregué el correo de mi nueva cuenta.

Comment: fijate https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59303/81450 , https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32775/81450 ,